# Mish Activation function is not correctly displayed in Model summary

Tags: python, tensorflow, keras

I wanted to replace an already loaded model in TensorFlow based on this [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49492255/how-to-replace-or-insert-intermediate-layer-in-keras-model), however, I came the problem that Mish activation function from [TensorFlow addons](https://www.tensorflow.org/addons/api_docs/python/tfa/activations/mish) does not display as a single layer in model summary:

[image]

as you can see, yes, the Mish is defined as tanh(softplus(x)), but this completely messes up with the Keras functionality! Does anyone know a way to work around this issue?

Comment: The TFA implementation of this activation is not a layer, also, what exactly breaks in Keras?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could use a custom activation function, instead of the one from tensorflow addons.

I've tried this [code](https://stackoverflow.com/a/65148465/14774959), and the summary is shown correctly:

```
def mish(inputs):
    x = tf.nn.softplus(inputs)
    x = tf.nn.tanh(x)
    x = tf.multiply(x, inputs)
    return x

model = tf.keras.Sequential([
            tf.keras.layers.Conv2D(filters=16, kernel_size=(3, 3), strides=(1, 1), 
                   input_shape=(28, 28, 1), activation='relu'),
            tf.keras.layers.MaxPool2D(pool_size=(2, 2)),
            tf.keras.layers.Conv2D(filters=32, kernel_size=(3, 3), strides=(1, 1), 
                   activation='relu'),
            tf.keras.layers.MaxPool2D(pool_size=(2, 2)),
            tf.keras.layers.Flatten(),
            tf.keras.layers.Dense(64, activation=mish, name="dense_mish"), 
            tf.keras.layers.Dropout(5e-1),
            tf.keras.layers.Dense(10, activation='softmax')])

model.compile(loss='categorical_crossentropy', optimizer='Adam')
```

Summary:

```
Model: "sequential"
_________________________________________________________________
 Layer (type)                Output Shape              Param #   
=================================================================
 conv2d (Conv2D)             (None, 26, 26, 16)        160       
                                                                 
 max_pooling2d (MaxPooling2D  (None, 13, 13, 16)       0         
 )                                                               
                                                                 
 conv2d_1 (Conv2D)           (None, 11, 11, 32)        4640      
                                                                 
 max_pooling2d_1 (MaxPooling  (None, 5, 5, 32)         0         
 2D)                                                             
                                                                 
 flatten (Flatten)           (None, 800)               0         
                                                                 
 dense_mish (Dense)          (None, 64)                51264 
                                                                   
 dropout (Dropout)           (None, 64)                0         
                                                                 
 dense_1 (Dense)             (None, 10)                650       
                                                                 
=================================================================
Total params: 56,714
Trainable params: 56,714
Non-trainable params: 0
_________________________________________________________________
```